# How to subtract two columns data for all the rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table as below

```
id  pausetime                 resumetime
-----------------------------------------------------
1   2021-09-22 14:21:34.023   2021-09-22 14:25:37.030
2   2021-09-22 14:37:47.810   2021-09-22 14:40:58.817
```

I want to subtract resumetime from pausetime for all the rows, then add that time so that I can get the total time between resume and pause, number of rows can be different .

How can I do that ?

I tried this

```
select 
    dbo.TimeDifference(cast(resumetime as time), 
    cast(pausetime as time)
```

but I have to do it for all the rows.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `DATEDIFF` here along with `SUM`:

```sql
SELECT SUM(DATEDIFF(ss, pausetime, resumetime)) AS total_diff_in_seconds
```